# How can I hide a program from another program?

Tags: windows, detection, process

If program A scans RAM, running processes and whatever, can I hide program B from being detected by A?

Basically, I don't want program A to detect program B, or at least, stop it from identifying it. Is this possible or is something like changing the file name enough?

I can't modify any of the files of program A, but I probably can with program B. Program A is looking for, knows the name and probably looks for behavior as well of program B.

Comment: So, you just want to hide the process name? Do you have control over program A, or just program B? Does program A know the name of program B and is looking for it? Is program A also looking at the behaviour of program B?

Comment: @schroeder I don't know what you mean exactly by control but I can't modify any of the files of program A but I probably can with program B. Yes, program A is looking for, knows the name and probably looks for behavior as well of program B. I don't know everything 100% but I guess every security measure is worth it (unless it requires too much time to do).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible.

This kind of behavior is seen on a class of programs called [rootkit](http://www.vanish.org/security/rootkits.htm). A rootkit employs a number of techniques to avoid detection.

Some of those techniques:

- **Thread injection**

  In this case, `Program B` [injects a thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection#Approaches_on_Microsoft_Windows) on another running process. If `Program A` is searching for `program_b.exe`, it will not find it.
- **Kernel Process Table manipulation**

  In this case, `Program B` [manipulates the kernel process table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_kernel_object_manipulation), removing itself from the list of running processes. It renders `Program B` invisible.
- **Polymorphism**

  In this case, `Program B` will create lots of copies of itself, each one different from the another. This is called [polymorphysm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_code). As there is lots of different ways to execute the same action, it can create virtually infinite copies of itself. If `Program A` is searching for the signature of `Program B`, it will fail to detect the variations.
- **Behavior change**

  `Program B` can have 2 modes of operation: safe and unsafe. Safe mode is how it will behave when it detects `Program A` running. As soon as it detects that `Program A` is not running, it loads anything it needs and enters unsafe mode, doing anything `Program A` would detect.

There's a [lot of another techniques](http://www.tripwire.com/state-of-security/security-data-protection/the-four-most-common-evasive-techniques-used-by-malware/), those are just a few samples. A quick search for *Detection avoidance*  will give you lots of pointers to research.

Comment: Sandboxing A is another option to hide from it.

Comment: Broken link on rootkit, maybe use https://web.archive.org/web/20171003081258/http://vanish.org:80/security/rootkits.htm