# how to disable detecting video capture

Tags: detection

I need to capture a video stream playing on a video player with my recording program. (windows 7)

But whenever I tried to run both of programs (video player and capture program) the video player stops with a message that there is a capture program running.

I think the video player can detect capture program running. I changed the name of the capture program but it doesn't work.

Is there any program that disable detection of capturing videos?
How can I capture the video stream?
Any idea would be welcome.

Comment: Does this cover it?  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/98411/how-can-i-hide-a-program-from-another-program?rq=1

Comment: try different players, but it's probably a window thing, not a capture app thing. they are making it harder to use windows to copy media, so don't be surprised if nothing works.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a security question

Answer (score 1):

The terms of use of the video streaming service most probably explicitly mark the subverting of security measures as illegal. 
Probably it's a large site if it has a detection mechanism like this. 
If it is legal for you to copy, you could try to find it on a torrent network.